# Not able to click ExtJS Dropdown button and select list elements - Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, extjs, selenium-webdriver

I am having difficulty in clicking a drop down and selecting option from the list. Below screenshot of the application.

[image]

Our application uses heavy ExtJS and below is the HTML code for dropdown button and textbox.

```
 <div id="combobox-1115-bodyEl" class="x-form-item-body x-form-trigger-wrap-focus" role="presentation" style="width: 325px;">
  <div id="ext-gen1273" class="x-hide-display x-form-data-hidden" role="presentation"></div>
   <input id="ext-gen1272" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-focus" type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" size="20" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Please Select a XXXX..." data-errorqtip="" style="width: 305px; -moz-user-select: text;" role="textbox" aria-describedby="combobox-1115-errorEl" aria-required="true"></input>
    <div id="combobox-1115-triggerWrap" class="x-form-trigger-wrap" role="presentation" style="width: 20px;">
    <div id="ext-gen1274" class="x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-form-trigger-last x-unselectable" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></div>
```

Below is the code for dropdown list options.

```
<div id="boundlist-1132" class="x-boundlist x-boundlist-floating x-boundlist-default x-layer x-boundlist-above" style="position: absolute; left: 582px; top: 93px; width: 325px; z-index: 19061;" role="listbox" tabindex="-1">
<div id="boundlist-1132-listEl" class="list-ct" style="overflow: auto;">
<ul>
<li id="ext-gen1312" class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">6757</li>
<li id="ext-gen1309" class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Customer 1</li>
<li id="ext-gen1300" class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Customer 2</li>
<li id="ext-gen1301" class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Customer 3</li>
<li id="ext-gen1302" class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Customer 4</li>
<li id="ext-gen1310" class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">XYZ Company1</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Please help me locate the dropdown button and select a list item from it. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I know you cannot use Select class here. But, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Saifur - Here am not able to locate and click down-arrow mark. I have used below 2 cssSelector codes to click it but it did not work...                              `By.cssSelector("div.x-form-trigger-wrap")).click();`                                        and `By.cssSelector("div.x-trigger-index-0.x-form-trigger.x-form-arrow-trigger.x-form-trigger-last.x-unselectable.x-form-trigger-over.x-form-arrow-trigger-over")).click();`

Comment: Two questions in that case? Is that a pop up window and can you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: @Saifur - Please refer the screenshot attached at the top. Am able to enter text in textbox for **Task**  but getting Unable to locate element exception when I try to locate dropdown down-arrow button for **Client**. I am not sure if its showModelWindow or pop up window. Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using explicit wait with more precise selectors.

```
By css = By.cssSelector("[placeholder='Please Select a Customer...']");
By option = By.xpath("//li[@role='option'][text()='Customer 2']");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

//Click the dropdown to populate the list
WebElement dropdown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(css));
dropdown.click();

//Click the option. Notice the xpath is using the text of the customer
WebElement value = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(xpath));
value.click();
```

Comment: I have tried your code and got this exception. `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //li[@role='option'][text()='Customer 2']`.  As I mentioned earlier, we need to click dropdown button(down-arrow button) first which will display the list and we can use your code to select item from list but here we have difficulty in locating dropdown button(down-arrow button).

Comment: Point me to the right direction then. Which line of `html` belongs to the dropdown?

Comment: When i check in Firebug below HTML line pointed to dropdwon `<div id="ext-gen1274" class="x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-form-trigger-last x-unselectable" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></div>`.

Comment: Have altered your answer lil and my problem solved. I have used `dropdown.sendKeys("Customer");` instead of `dropdown.click()` and it displayed all the options with **'Customer'** text then I clicked **'Customer 2'** from the options.That's it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to click dropdown element(mostly with input tag) and then wait for the li webelemnt to appear .. below is the function which expects webelement with ul tag and value.

```
    public void selectValueFromUnorderedList(WebElement unorderedList, final String value) {
    List<WebElement> options = unorderedList.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

    for (WebElement option : options) {
        //System.out.println(option.getText());
        if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(option.getText())) {
            option.click();
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But here I have difficulty in clicking dropdown button. I have added screenshot and code for your reference in question. Please suggest how I can locate dropdown button and click it.

Comment: if you are unable to locate this element itself ? if so try using firebug extension for firefox and locate it..

Comment: if you knew the location.. try finding out if this element is visible.. public static boolean isElementVisible(final WebDriver driver, By by) {


  try {
   WebElement web = driver.findElement(by);
   web.isDisplayed();
   
   return true;
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
   return false;
  }
 }

Comment: it seems like ID's are generated dynamically.. it better to use xpath or cssSelector.. some thing like [id *="ext-gen"]

Comment: Yes, I am having difficulty in locating element itself. I got below code for dropdown button when I used firebug but I am not able to click it. `<div id="ext-gen1274" class="x-trigger-index-0 x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger x-form-trigger-last x-unselectable" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;"></div>`. I have below this Webdriver code to locate element but it dint work. `By.cssSelector("div.x-trigger-index-0.x-form-trigger.x-form-arrow-trigger.x-for‌​m-trigger-last.x-unselectable.x-form-trigger-over.x-form-arrow-trigger-over")).cl‌​ick();`.

Comment: locator which you mentioned doesn't seems to be dropdown arrow button.. mostly it will be input tag.. try to paste entire screenshot of html source and with firepath being clicked on the element..

Comment: I have altered @Saifur code and my problem solved. Thanks for suggestions.